# Split a filename in 2 groups

Tags: c#, split, project, filenames

I am making an application which "Filewatches" a folder and when a file is created in there it will automatically be mailed to the customer.

The problem is that i haven't found any information on how to split filenames

For example i have a file called : "Q1040500005.xls"

I need the first 5 characters seperated from the last 5, so basically split it in half (without the extension ofcourse)

And my application has to recognize the "Q1040" and the "500005" as seperate strings.
Which will be recognized in the database which contains The query number (Q1040) and the customer number "500005" the email of the customer and the subject of the queryfile.

How can i do this the easiest way?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SubString method http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aka44szs(v=vs.80).aspx

```
int lengthFilename = filename.Length - 4; //substract the string ".xls";
int middleLength = lengthFilename/2;
String filenameA = filename.SubString(0, middleLength);
String filenameB = filename.SubString(middleLength, lengthFilename - middleLength);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `string.Substring` method what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.SubString()` here

```
string a  = fileName.SubString(0, 5); // "Q1040"
string b  = fileName.SubString(5, 5); // "50000" <- Are you sure you didn't mean "last 6"?
string b2 = fileName.SubString(5, 6); // "500005"
```

This only works, if both strings have a constant fixed length

**Edit:**

If on the other hand, both strings can have variable length, I'd recommend you use a separator to divide them (`"Q1040-500005.xml"`), then use `string.Split()`

```
string[] separatedStrings = fileName.Split(new char[] { '-', '.' });
string a         = separated[0]; // "Q1040"
string b         = separated[1]; // "500005"
string extension = separated[2]; // "xls"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.SubString(int startindex, int length)`

```
String filename = Q1040500005.xls

var queryNumber = filename.Substring(0, 5); //Q1040
var customerNumber = filename.Substring(5, 6); //500005
```

This assumes your strings are a constant length.

Hope this helps.